# Why is my test failing with true == true

Tags: xctest

I am writing an XCTest

in my test i have `BOOL stam = true;`

and then `XCTest(stam == true,@"value is expected to be true");`

however, the test is failing and i get this error message

```
((value == true) is true) failed - value is expected to be true
```

Comment: Per Apple source file `XCAbstractTest.h`, 

"`XCTest` is an abstract base class for testing. … Most developers will not need to subclass XCTest directly."  The various XCTAssert() methods would seem more appropriate to use.

Answer (score 0):

You typically need to use the Assertion methods in testing frameworks.

Did you try

```
XCTAssertEqual(stam,true,@"value is expected to be true");
```